# Summation Identity for Stirling Numbers of the First Kind

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, stirling-numbers

For the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), the following identity is well-known:
\begin{align}
S(n,l) = \sum_{k_1 + \cdots + k_l = n-l} 1^{k_1} 2^{k_2} \cdots l^{k_{l}},
\end{align}
where the sum is taken over non-negative integers satisfying $0 \leqslant k_1 \leqslant \cdots \leqslant k_l \leqslant n- l$. Is an analogous identity known for $s(n,l)$, the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind)?

*Edit*: Thanks to Raymond, the correct formula is
\begin{align}
s(n,l) = (-1)^{n-l} \mathop{\sum_{k_1 + \cdots +k_{n-1} = n-l}}_{0 \leqslant k_i \leqslant 1} 1^{k_1} 2^{k_2} \cdots (n-1)^{k_{n-1}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes ([26.8.3](http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.8) of DLMF) :

$$(-1)^{n-k}s(n,k)=\sum_{1\leq b_1<\cdots<b_{n-k}\leq n-1} b_1 b_2\cdots b_{n-k} $$